# How to create loading image on page redirect on the time in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I need to show the loading image when I am going to click the button and redirect to the next page in asp.net.....thanks in advance

Comment: I want to do this using jquery or ajax

Answer (score 0):

You can use a JavaScript to show the loading effect if your page is taking too much time or else you can set the timings to show a loading effect. Nevertheless JavaScript is a good option. You can find some very good JavaScripts on the Net that will be helpful to you.

Ex.

Comment: I want to do this using jquery or ajaz

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code:

```
In css class:

.divModalBackground
{
filter: alpha(opacity=50); -moz-opacity:0.5; opacity: 0.5;
width:100%;
background-color: #999988;
position: absolute;
top: 0px; 
left: 0px;
z-index: 800;
}
```

In aspx page:

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" Height="900px" Width="100%" 
 CssClass="divModalBackground" Visible="true" >
<asp:Image runat="Server" ID="ImageLoader" CssClass="LoadingProgress"  
ImageUrl="../../App_Themes/Black/images/ajax-loader.gif" />
</asp:Panel>
```

In aspx.cs page I put the code like this:

//to show modal popup at page startup

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
base.OnInit(e);
Panel1.Visible = true;
}
```

In aspx page place this

// to clear the modal background when page load complete, place this code at the end of your page just before the end of the form tag

```
<script type="text/javascript" > 
function init() 
{ 
var objdiv=document.getElementById('<%=Panel1.ClientID%>') 
if(objdiv) 
{
objdiv.style.visibility = 'hidden'; 
} 
} 
init(); 
</script>
```

Comment: I want to do this using ajax or jquery

Answer (score 0):

Use following code

```
$(function() { 
    ($.unblockUI);   
    $('#pnlLogin_btnOk').click(function() {
        $.blockUI({ message: '<img src="Images/loading.gif" />' });
    });
});
```

Comment: This requires the [tag:blockui] plugin